# Same name input/output issue

Tags: c, input, io

Okay guys, I'm having one more issue with my program.
I'm running into an issue with using the same filename (KnightsBall."extension"). I don't know if it's something locally, or an issue I'll have when I move the code over. So can anyone help me with what thing I'm overlooking? The output and input have to both go to the same filename.(in) or (out) so no ways around. If I change the output file to `knights.out` it works. Any ideas?
Relevant segments of code:

```
FILE *fr; 
FILE *fo;

typedef struct KnightsBallLottoPlayer 
{
char firstName[20];
char lastName[20];
int numbers[6];
} KBLottoPlayer;


int main()
{
KBLottoPlayer *temp;
int numPlays=0;
//What file to read from
fr = fopen("KnightsBall.in", "r");
//What file to read to
fo = fopen("KnightsBall.out", "w");
```

and the part where the output is accessed:

```
if(match==3)
    fprintf(fo,"%s %s matched %d numbers and won $10.\n", temp[r].firstName, temp[r].lastName, match);
if(match==4)
    fprintf(fo,"%s %s matched %d numbers and won $100.\n", temp[r].firstName, temp[r].lastName, match);
if(match==5)
    fprintf(fo,"%s %s matched %d numbers and won $10000.\n", temp[r].firstName, temp[r].lastName, match);
if(match==6)
    fprintf(fo,"%s %s matched %d numbers and won $1000000.\n", temp[r].firstName, temp[r].lastName, match);
```

Also on a completely unrelated side note, does anyone know how to close the command prompt after I scan in the values I need from the user? All help is much appreciated.

Comment: I'm not quite sure of what your question is. Did you say you had problem reading and writing simultaneously to KightsBall.in?

Comment: No. I read in from KnightsBall.in. After processing the information, i have to output the fprintf statements to KnightsBall.out. The problem Im having is that reading in always works, but the writing out to KnightsBall.out does nothing to the file. If I changed KnightsBall.out to Knights.out it works marvelously. Any ideas?

Comment: Ah, I see; that's curious. Are you sure you are checking the file's contents only after closing it using fclose() ?

Comment: I never close the file using fclose() actually. I tried that and it didnt work either.

Comment: Create an empty file called "KnightsBall.out" manually. Run your program. If that doesn't work, there is a bug somewhere else that is not shown here.

Comment: You could use [`fflush`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904875/functions/fflush.html) rigth after fprintf call to flush the contents to the file. But on program exit or file close that would happen anyway. You claim that even after `fclose` contents are not flushed to the file so the guess would be the faulty code is elsewhere. Also, it is better to check the return values of `fopen` & `fprintf`. The return value of `fprintf` might provide some hints.

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't show the code where you check that you opened each file successfully, it is probable that you didn't open the output file.  It is not clear why, but one possible problem is that the output file already exists and is read-only.  Another might be that you don't have permission to create files in the directory.

I can't help but think you could use an array of strings to reduce the printing to:

```
static const char *amounts[] = { "", "", "", "10", "100", "10000", "1000000" };
if (match >= 3 && match <= 6)
    fprintf(fo, "%s %s matched %d numbers and won $%s.\n",
            temp[r].firstName, temp[r].lastName, match, amounts[match]);
```

Since there isn't a simple relation between the values, it is probably best to use a table rather than a calculation for the amounts.

Comment: If the opening of file failed, then `fo` would be `NULL`, then won't fprintf would result in a segmentation fault? But then again, as you have mentioned the faulty code has not been posted.

Comment: Typically, on a Unix-ish box, you'd get a core dump.  I dunno what you get on Windows; the partial question about 'how to close the command prompt' suggests a Windows platform.  However, technically, you get undefined behaviour; anything can happen and it is OK.